# 'object has no attribute' when running TestCase

Tags: django, django-testing

I´m following a django tests tutorial, but in my case the AttributeError appears

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework.test import APIClient    

class RecipeImageUploadTests(TestCase):

    def setUP(self):
        self.client = APIClient()
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            'user@kubousky.com',
            'testpass'
    )
        self.client.force_authenticate(self.user)
        self.recipe = sample_recipe(user=self.user)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.recipe.image.delete()

    def test_upload_image_to_recipe(self):
        """Test uploading an image to recipe"""
        url = image_upload_url(self.recipe.id)
```

The error refers to "self.recipe" says: 'RecipeImageUploadTests' object has no attribute 'recipe'

There is not much about setUP() in docs. Wonder why I can set self.user and not any other attribute

Comment: It is `setUp`, not `setUP`.

Comment: Thank you Willem!